# How to print out values while debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

In Xcode I am able to "po" any values while debugging. Is there a way to do this in Android Studio?

For example, if I hit a breakpoint and want to print out certain values in realtime as opposed to having to use Logs in my code?

Comment: @Bhargav Yes, that would suffice. Basically I am used to doing this in the console in iOS development and am wondering how I can do it in Android Studio

Comment: you can't do that sadly, printing to logcat requires the runtime to execute commands like system.out.println

Comment: @Bhargav "Watches" appears to be what I was looking for. I can enter any expression while at a break point and see it's value. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Watches](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/debug-tool-window-watches.html). It gives you the ability to evaluate expressions.

Comment: "Watches" appears to be what I was looking for. Within the Debugger tab at the bottom of Android Studio I am able to track the value of any expression (by clicking the add button). Now I can debug efficiently, thanks

Answer (score 17):

You can do the following steps:

1- Set **BreakPoint** in the line you want to evaluate `Ctrl+F8`.

2- Run your code in debug mode or press `Shift+F9`.

3- When reached to the **BreakPoint** `press Alt+F8` or click on the following button.

[image]

4- Then type your value in text-field and click on the **Evaluate** button.

[image]

**References**:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html

Answer (score 5):

When you hit debug point, there are two ways to check values :

(1) Add Watch for any variable

[image]

(2) Hover over any variable, the value will be displayed there

Answer (score 0):

If it's a c/c++ project, you still can use lldb command in Android Studio.
Here's the [official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug). When you hit the breakpoint, you will see a tab named "lldb" next to the variables tab.